# Default value in custom field cannot be searched

Tags: civievent

i am working on CiviCRM 4.6.10 and came across this problem which doesn't seemed to be asked on the web:

1. I created a custom field with radio button of 3 options
2. I defaulted the field to one of the value and made it a required field
3. When a new contact is created through a event registration, the field does not show any value when the contact is viewed through in "View Contact".
4. Searching or reporting that use the field as a column shows nothing in the field
5. However, upon clicking the field in View Contact, it shows the defaulted value
6. After saving the field without changing anything, the field now shows the defaulted value
7. Searching and reporting using the field as a column now shows the default value as expected

I suppose this would be a bug ?  Thanks for your time and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is your answer. There are two processes involved in getting a field on an event

1. add a Custom Set of Fields and then create the field
2. display the field in the Profile

so if you want a default value showing on the Event you need to set it when you add the Field to the Profile (ie 2.), you do not need to make the field itself.